# Should I vote to close a question that I asked if I later find out it is a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, closing

Recently I asked [a question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/182320/what-kind-of-game-is-flappy-bird-swing-copters) about what genre a particular set of games falls under.  It was answered and accepted, and the answer given recieved 10 votes (though the question recieved 2 upvotes and 2 downvotes).

Today, while making an edit to a question that uses the same tag as mine, I found [another question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/29401/what-is-the-name-of-the-genre-of-games-similar-to-jetpack-joyride) that is very close to, if not an exact duplicate of, my own.

I've voted to close my question as a duplicate, rather than delete the question, because I feel like duplicate questions should be recorded for future askers to see and understand why the question was closed.

Is this the right way to handle a question you asked that recently you found to be a duplicate?